# creating new arff dataset with selected attributes in weka

Tags: weka, arff

I want to create a new arff dataset using a  selected set of attributes. I have selected 20 random indices.How to create a new arff file using these selected attributes?

```
int indices;    
DataSource source = new DataSource("E:/dataset/lukemia.arff");
Instances toreduce = source.getDataSet();
Random generator = new Random();
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
     indices = generator.nextInt(toreduce.numAttributes());
    System.out.println(indices);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Remove` filter

```
Instances data = ...;
int[] r = new int[indexes.size()];
// r contains indexes you want to remove
Remove rmv = new Remove();
rmv.setAttributeIndicesArray(r);
rmv.setInputFormat(data);
Instances newDataset = Filter.useFilter(data, rmv);
```

For your case you may want to set `invertSelection` to `true` (before using the filter, of course):

```
rmv.setInvertSelection(true);
```

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69923824/appending-two-files-in-weka