# appending two files in Weka

Tags: append, weka

I have two datasets. Basically, they are two .arff file.

Fold1.arff contains:

```
@relation iris

@attribute sepallength numeric
@attribute sepalwidth numeric
@attribute petallength numeric
@attribute petalwidth numeric
@attribute class {Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}

@data
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.7,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.1,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5,3.5,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
7,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5,2,3.5,1,Iris-versicolor
5.9,3.2,4.8,1.8,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.6,4.4,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.3,3.3,6,2.5,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.2,5.1,2,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.2,5.7,2.3,Iris-virginica
7.4,2.8,6.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.1,5.6,2.4,Iris-virginica
```

Fold2.arff contains

```
@relation iris

@attribute sepallength numeric
@attribute sepalwidth numeric
@attribute petallength numeric
@attribute petalwidth numeric
@attribute class {Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}

@data
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.7,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.5,2.3,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.9,3,4.2,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.8,4,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.7,1,Iris-versicolor
6.1,3,4.6,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.7,5.3,1.9,Iris-virginica
5.6,2.8,4.9,2,Iris-virginica
7.9,3.8,6.4,2,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.1,5.1,2.3,Iris-virginica
```

Now I try to append them using the command:

```
java weka.core.Instances append d:\fold1.arff d:\fold2.arff > d:\result.arff
```

I run the command from the Weka simple CLI field.

I got this error:

```
Usage:
weka.core.Instances help
    Prints this help
weka.core.Instances <filename>
    Outputs dataset statistics
weka.core.Instances merge <filename1> <filename2>
    Merges the datasets (must have same number of rows).
    Generated dataset gets output on stdout.
weka.core.Instances append <filename1> <filename2>
    Appends the second dataset to the first (must have same number of attributes).
    Generated dataset gets output on stdout.
weka.core.Instances headers <filename1> <filename2>
    Compares the structure of the two datasets and outputs whether they
    differ or not.
weka.core.Instances randomize <seed> <filename>
    Randomizes the dataset and outputs it on stdout.
```

My two files have same number of rows as you can see from the above example. Then why the result.arff file could not create?

Comment: Works fine for me (under Linux). Maybe try forward slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in your two files that the attributes are same and has same number of attributes (5 in total)

From the [official documentation](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#main(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) the current syntax for append is

```
    weka.core.Instances append <filename1> <filename2>
```

This appends filename2 to filename1. No need to specify the output file. That is all changes are stored in filename1 itself

**Note**
It’s ideal to pass file name in quotes (single or double quotes) especially in scenarios when your filename has blank space (eg., `fold 1.arff` instead of `fold1.arff`)

```
      java weka.core.Instances append “d:\fold1.arff” “d:\fold2.arff”
```

In few languages, blackslash is an escape sequence and so has to be used twice

```
      java weka.core.Instances append “d:\\fold1.arff” “d:\\fold2.arff”
```